# Safe way to BULK INSERT a CSV file in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

AS many before, I've fallen into the BULK INSERT hell with SQL Server and CSV files. I've tried to follow basically all the previous anwers but with no luck.

e.g.

```
'BULK INSERT ' + @Table
    + ' FROM ''' + @Path + @Table + '.csv'' WITH (
        FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '';'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\r\n'', TABLOCK ) '
```

Good thing is I can create the CSV files from scratch (I'm on windows, but i'd need them to work in Linux as well.)

Is there a safe method\code combination to create a CSV file on Windows that will be read by BULK INSERT in both Linux and Windows?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would change the ROWTERMINATOR from `''\ r \ n''` to `''0x0a''`

Comment: Read what you wrote. If you knew nothing about this code, your data, your schema, and the process used, would you be able to provide any help? What does "no luck" mean? Is the problem with your construction of dynamic sql? Is it with the execution of your dynamic sql? Maybe permissions to the randomly named file you attempt to insert? Maybe you should use a different approach - not one based on executing this from the server instance but from a client machine?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I've been able to solve it by using ANSI encoding and by substituting all the `;` with `,`. The code I used is the following: `'BULK INSERT ' + @Table + ' FROM ''' + @Path + @Table + '.csv'' WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'`